# Trying to `yield` to a `co( fn ).call`

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, ecmascript-harmony, co

I'm having a problem getting co to resume when also changing it's context value:

```
var co = require( 'co' );

function *foo( next ){
    console.log( 'foo yielding' );
    yield next;
    console.log( 'foo yielded' );

    return 42;
}

var bar = co( function *(){
    console.log( 'bar yielding' );

    // this is the bit that I'm having problems with
    yield function( cb ){    
        return co( foo ).call(
              { name: 'this object' }
            , function(){ console.log( 'in next' ); }
            , cb
        );
    };

    console.log( 'bar yielded' );
} );

bar();
```

The above logs:

```
bar yielding
foo yielding
in next
```

I've tried wrapping the `co( foo ).call` line in a function, a generator function, and a bunch of other things.  I can't get it to work... help!

Note that if I call `co` normally, it works.  But then I can't set the context of, or pass arguments to, the function I'm trying to call:

```
yield co( foo );
```

Answer (score 0):

My next function needed a callback, and it needs to execute it:

```
, function( cb ){ console.log( 'in next' ); cb(); }
```

otherwise the chain gets halted, gah

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you try to achieve, but I assume you want to see

```
bar yielding
foo yielding
in next
foo yielding
bar yielding
```

Try this code:

```
var co = require( 'co' );

function *foo( next ){
    console.log( 'foo yielding' );
    yield next;
    console.log( 'foo yielded' );

    return 42;
}

var bar = co( function *(){
    console.log( 'bar yielding' );

    // this is the bit that I'm having problems with
    yield co( foo ).bind(
              { name: 'this object' }
            , function(cb){ console.log( 'in next, name: ' + this.name ); process.nextTick(cb) }
        );

    console.log( 'bar yielded' );
} );

bar();
```

Couple of footnotes:

- if you yield a function, it is supposed to be a thunk, that is, it accepts one argument and it is callback;
- you need to call this callback, it's also a good idea to do that asynchronously;

Applying this your code: 
 - you yield a function, but never call it's `cb` argument;
 - the same with `next`.